# Single package to allow signing in with oauth through several social networks?

Tags: facebook, twitter, oauth, linkedin-api

I'm looking for a way to allow users to sign in to my site using Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn, and Google. A good example of a site that does this is [Answers.com](http://www.answers.com/), on the homepage they have a set of buttons, and each button gives a simple pop up window to confirm the connection.

I know that I can implement each connection individually, but I want to know if there is a single package that provides all of this functionality for the different social networks.

Edit: I'm looking for a package in PHP.

Comment: PHP. I meant to add that in originally, I've edited it now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Those sites, just like this one, implement OpenID or OAuth.  So just do a search for OpenID PHP or OAuth PHP and you'll find a bunch of information.  (I have not implemented either in PHP, but we are considering implementing OpenID in .NET.)

Comment: OAuth was painful to implement in .NET last time I looked