# Is there a good multi-target OAuth-Framework out there?

Tags: php, facebook, twitter, oauth

I'm momentarily looking for a good solution for PHP-based logins via OAuth etc. It should already implement everything for Twitter, Facebook, Google, etc -- I wouldn't want to invent the wheel twice. Best case solution would be such an easy logon like here on SO.

Is there a good framework out there? Has anyone recommendations?

I already found [this](http://uswaretech.com/blog/2009/08/django-socialauth-login-via-twitter-facebook-openid-yahoo-google/), but it only works for Python.

Edit: There is already a question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250689/single-package-to-allow-signing-in-with-oauth-through-several-social-networks), but noone came up with an answer :-(

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Janrain Engage](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage). It should be easy to install, support a lot of services, and have a PHP library.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will use http://www.janrain.com/openid-enabled, but there are still two points open: 1st) I can't find a license for the libray and 2nd) it looks like the php library hasn't been maintained for a while...

Answer (score 1):

[opauth](http://opauth.org/) may be what you're looking for, [up-to-date list of supported sites](https://github.com/opauth/opauth/wiki/List-of-strategies)

Answer (score 0):

I just googled "php oauth" and I find this [oauth-php](http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/) library which looks to be very good. You can find an example in the Wiki.

Cheers,

Comment: Yes, this is a OAuth library, but it has no (build-in) support for facebook, twitter, etc. Not having to care about them is the main reason for me to look for an all-in-on solution. Thanks for your answer anyway!